# Sorting a list of tuples based on length of first element of a tuple in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am having a list of tuples in python. I am trying to sort the list based on the length of first element of tuple.

```
mylist=[('abcde', 23), ('this is one string', 234), ('sa', 2346)]
```

to be sorted to

```
[('sa', 2346), ('abcde', 23), ('this is one string', 234)]
```

based on length of first element of tuple.
I tried

```
mylist=sorted(mylist,key=len)
```

which is not working.

Comment: No, because they are all `len(thing) == 2`. Do you actually have *strings* in those tuples, or...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `lambda` function as key for sort in couple with `len` method of string:

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: len(x[0]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You're close, you just need to index out element `[0]` then take the `len` of that

```
>>> sorted(mylist, key = lambda i: len(i[0]))
[('sa', 2346), ('abcde', 23), ('this is one string', 234)]
```